# Formik Validation Display Problem with bootstrap css

Tags: reactjs

My React.js code imports the below.

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

With this import, the Formik validation does not work and is not shown.

```
<Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
{formik.errors.name}
</Form.Control.Feedback>
```

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented it like this.

```
  {formik.errors["name"] && (
     <div className="has-error">
        <HelpBlock>{formik.errors["name"]}</HelpBlock>
     </div>
  )}
```

The above code conditionally renders the error message.